# Build a list of values from queryset list (pk__in) in special order

Tags: python, django, django-views

i have a model with ratings, the results of a filter query must be in a special order for chartit (comparing ratings for trainee's) but I can't find the right way to do it. (ok I'm new to Django and python ;)

```
class Bewertung(models.Model):
    auffassung = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    interesse = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    arbeitsabw = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    aufmerksamkeit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    arbeitsgenauigkeit = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    verhalten = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    ausb_sach = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ausb_fuehr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

the query:

```
qs = Bewertung.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
```

I want to compare the integer values in a  multi bar chart e.g.

auffassung_from_pk(1,2,3) interesse_from_pk(1,2,3) .. n

but every try ends in a list with a lot of unordered values 
(Auffassung_from_pk(1), interesse_from_pk(1), Auffassung_from_pk(2) ..)

I can't find a way to solve it nice and efficient in an python way.
so I need a little help, can you help?

Comment: You want to separate the fields in the model from the filtered queryset ?

Comment: How are the multiple filters applied?

Answer (score 0):

@Sachin Kukreja correct, separate it and order it. so every field (e.g. auffassung must be one list with every result from the queryset.)

if I have 3 resulting query sets (pk_list=(1,2,3)) I need something like ((1,2,1),(2,3,3)...) ((auffassung),(interesse))

@Rajez there are no multiple filters

i set all my approach's to zero to start new. I have only this (in the Django shell)

```
for q in qs:
    print(q.auffassung)
    print(q.interesse)
```

i am really struggling at this at the moment

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
import itertools

qs = Bewertung.objects.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
values = qs.values_list('auffassung', 'interesse')

result = list(itertools.chain(*values))
```